# Is it possible to use neo4j totally on memory without persistency and still be able to utilize the graph algorithms plug-in?

Tags: java, performance, neo4j

The graph-algo plug-in is essential for me and I don`t need persistency at all. I only need the cypher querying features of neo4j but my application totally slows down by writing and reading from the disk (due to persistency).

Answer (score 0):

You typically have two modes for most of the Graph Algorithm procedures, either to stream results, or to write back results. Do check that you're using the streaming output, which will output a results stream without making changes to the graph.

If you're running a number of algorithms on the same graph, you may find the [named graph](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/projected-graph-model/named-graph/) procedures useful.

Comment: Thank you, I know about the difference of streaming functions. Actually, I want to load my whole database into the memory and be able to use the cypher capabilities as well as the extra graph algorithms. I also want to go on inserting and deleting relationships from the database loaded to the memory. The named graphs seem nice for this but it looks like it only loads a certain part of the database and I am not sure if it allows to perform write/delete operations on the loaded graph. In my case, there are 2 types of nodes and 3 types of relationships that all need to be uploaded to memory.